# express.js не могу получить post данные из формы

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, express, html-form

Есть следующая форма:

```
<form id="form" action="/" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="title">
    <input type="text" id="data">
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="отправить">
</form>
```

и файл server.js:

```
var express     = require("express");

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var multer = require('multer'); // v1.0.5
var upload = multer(); // for parsing multipart/form-data

var app     = express();


app.use(bodyParser.json()); // for parsing application/json
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // for parsing application/x-www-form-urlencoded

app.set("view engine","ejs");

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

app.get("/", function(req,res){
    res.render("pages/index", {
        title: "Главная",
        msg: "Привет Мир!",
        data: q,
        info: ""
    }); 
});

app.post('/', upload.array(), function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.body);            //{}
  console.log(req.body.title);      //undefined
  console.log(req.body.data);       //undefined

  res.json(req.body);               //{}
});

app.get("/hello", function(req,res){
    res.render("pages/other", {
        title: "Другая страница",
        msg: "hello world"
    }); 
});


app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.status(404).render("pages/error", {
        title: "ошибка 404",
        msg: "ошибка 404"
    });

    res.status(500).render("pages/error", {
        title: "ошибка 500",
        msg: "ошибка 500"
    });
});


app.listen(8080);
console.log("Сервер запущен!");
```

Делаю по туториалам, недавно начал с этим разбираться, столкнулся с тем, что создал форму, но получить на сервере данные никак я не могу. пробовал и req.query, и req.params('title') -- undefined.

Пакеты установил которые подключаю.

Собственно... много информации на английском языке -- может я что то упускаю?

Вопрос: Как получить данные из формы передаваемые методом post и обработать их на сервере используя технологии nodejs и express.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для отправки данных формы необходимо проименовать поля.

```html
<form id="form" action="/" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="title" id="title">
    <input type="text" name="data" id="data">
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="отправить">
</form>
```

В name - с каким названием параметр прилетит серверу. id - ид инпута для браузера, с сервером не связан никак.

Comment: `app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.status(404).render("pages/error", {
        title: "ошибка 404",
        msg: "ошибка 404"
    });

    res.status(500).render("pages/error", {
        title: "ошибка 500",
        msg: "ошибка 500"
    });
});`
оставьте один обработчик res.status()... иначе когда дойдете до этого места - рискуете положить приложение

Comment: Вообще, для подобных ситуаций лучше проверять, отправляется ли что-либо из браузера. Это можно сделать через инструменты разработчика, которые есть в любом браузере (честно, не знаю про IE, скорее всего тоже есть уже), в разделе работы с сетью.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Оно заработало! ...да я подозревал, что дело в name, но памяти засела некая устаревшая особенность работы с тегами "a" и якорями где name больше не используют.